# HTTP POST Routing and Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, routes

how can i get a parameter i passed in an httppost request back in the post method in c#. In the method below, i'm passing string GtrId and string Username into the HTTPPost method, but i don't know how to pass it back into a new variable in the same method. This is what i have tried but i don't know if it looks right.

```
[HttpPost]
public void GTRDetail(string GtrID, string username)
{
    if (GtrID != null && username != null)
    {
        var acct = GtrID;
        var user = username;
    }                   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "don't know if it looks right"? Does it do what you want it to do? Does `acct` and `user` end up containing the data you wanted? And why would you just assign those values to new variables anyways, why not just continue using `GtrID` and `username` directly?